# SpringBoot Maven Project Update not working

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot, and I am trying to work with sts-3.6.3SR1. Please find the attached file of the pom.xml file:

[image]

while i click update maven project, it's showing an error:

> Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.18.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was 
>    cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are 
>    forced.
>
> Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.18.1 from/to central 
>    (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org"

Comment: In Update Maven Project section , i tried Force Update of Snapshots/Releases, but its not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wow, i have opened the folder "C:\Users\kangkan pc.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-surefire-pl‌​ugin\2.18.1 " and deleted the *.lastupdate file, then try Update Maven Project again.. And now its working fine .. anyways Thanks guys.